# Ionic 2 Provider

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 and am trying to get through any of the tutorials online that show how to add a provider. It seems that Ionic has changed the app structure the is generated. can some please give me an example of how to do this with the current Ionic 2 app structure? Everywhere I try to import and add my provider to the page class (Constructor and @Component page decorator), I get an error that it cannot be found.  All I am trying to do is follow [this](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/) tutorial with the current Ionic 2 app structure.

Answer (score 5):

In `app.module.ts'

```
import { PeopleService } from '../providers/people-service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Declarations commented out for brevity
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    // Entry Components commented out for brevity
  ],
  providers: [PeopleService] // Add PeopleService provider
})
```

and then on 'home-page.ts'

```
import {PeopleService} from '../providers/people-service/people-service';

export class HomePage {
public people: any;

    constructor(public peopleService: PeopleService){

      }
    }
```

Comment: This is what the current app.module.ts file providers section looks like;

providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]

I tried it like this and it does not work, any sugesstions?

providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }, PeopleService]

Comment: Here is home.ts file

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TestProvider } from '../providers/test-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public testProvider: TestProvider) {

  }

}

Comment: The TestProvider in the constructor is causing and error. This what I am calling my provider.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a provider by running

```
> ionic g provider storage-provider
```

This will generate a ready template

And then add this using import to your app.modules.ts file

```
> import { StorageProvider } from '../providers/storage-provider';
> import { IonicApp, IonicModule  } from 'ionic-angular';
```

And then in the same app.modules.ts file,  you go to the providers section at the very bottom in the file Add the StorageProvider class

```
providers: [AuthProvider,  UtilProvider,**StorageProvider**  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an ionic 2 tutorial created one year before is a quite bad idea if you are on the current version.

The idea of Angular 2 is to organise your app with module but if we look the ionic projects, there is usually juste one module which is using components.

Ionic team's github repository is often a good way to find great informations, so to answer your question: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tabs this one show you what you're looking for.